# Special Sorting

Tags: algorithm

There is an external array of integers on which you can perform the following operations in O(1) time.

1. get(int i) - returns the value at the index 'i' in the external array.
2. reverse( int i, int j) - returns the reverse of the array between index positions i and j (including i and j).

example for reverse: consider an array {1,2,3,4,5}. reverse(0,2) will return {3,2,1,4,5} and reverse(1,4) will return {1,5,4,3,2}.

Write a code to sort the external array. Mention the time and space complexity for your code.

Obviously We can sort in nlogn using quick sort or merge sort. But given the scenerio can we do better?

Comment: Only get and reverse are counted for calculating the complexity and internal operations are free?

Comment: Need to sort array using get() and reverse()?

Comment: I think we need to optimize based on these... we can sort in nlogn using quick sort or merge sort But given the scenerio can we do better?

Comment: How come on earth someone can downvote such a good question...It will discourage people to post any interesting questions...

Comment: @user973931 It is a bad question, because it's unclear, for example, if the cost of internal operations is to be considered. This has led to confusion and led to many downvotes already.

Comment: Ok thanks will never post so called BAD questions again.... I voted to delete it... please do the same..

Comment: @user973931 Just fill in the missing info and the downvotes will go away.

Comment: I have asked what I was asked in interview... I cannot go to interviewer and ask this now.. sorry .... and as I said I will never post these kind of questions again.. Thank You downvoters!!!

Comment: i think this is an interesting question.. instead of downvoting, you can just ask if you have questions. +1 to let it stay

Comment: @xvatar: The questions were asked in the comments. No reaction.

Comment: is this really a sort, or are you just swapping elements in the array? for instance if you had `{7,3,5,6,8,9}` and you reverse(0,2) do you get `{5,3,7,6,8,9}`?

Answer (score 3):

To sort an array is to find the permutation, or shuffle, that restores it to a sorted state. In other words, your algorithm determines which of the `n!` possible permutations must be applied, and applies it. Since your algorithm explores the array by asking yes-no questions (Is cell `i` smaller or greater than cell `j`?) it follows an implicit decision tree that has depth `log(n!) ~ n*log(n)`.

**This means there will be `O(n*log(n))` calls to `get()` to determine how to sort the array.**

An interesting variant is to determine the smallest number of calls to `reverse()` necessary to sort the array, once you know what permutation you need. We know that this number is smaller than `n-1`,  which can be achieved by using selection sort. Can the worst case number be smaller than `n-2` ? I must say that I have no idea...

Comment: You don't have to call `get` repeatedly, you can save the value. It is unclear from the question if working on saved values should be considered or not.

Comment: If working on saved values is allowed, then there is a trivial answer to the problem : read every value once, perform a selection sort on the stored values, and apply the resulting shufle using `reverse()`. This is an `O(n)` algorithm, which is the absolute lower bound for sorting `n` items. I might as well assume that there are no such obvious uninteresting solutions and deal with the real interesting things.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to reduce the problem to a classic `swaps()` based sorting algorithm.

In the following we assume without loss of generality `j>=i`:

Note that `swap(i,j) = reverse(i,j)` for each `j <= i+2`, the reversed sub array is only swapping the edges if there are 3 or less elements

Now, for any `j>i+2` - all you need is just `reverse()` the array, by this swapping the edges - and then reverse the "middle" to get it back to the original, so you get: `swap(i,j) = reverse(i,j) ; reverse(i+1,j-1)`

Using the just built `swap()`, you can use any compare based algorithms that uses swaps, such as [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), which is `O(nlogn)`. The complexity remains `O(nlogn)` since for each `swap()` you need up to 2 `reverse()` ops, which is `O(1)`

**EDIT:** Note: This solution fits for the *original* question (before it was editted), which asked for *a solution*, and not to optimize it better then quicksort/mergesort.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (`But given the scenerio can we do better?`).

Comment: @WolframH: The quoted line was not in the original question. This answer holds for the original version of the question, which only asked "how it can be done?"

Comment: True. (This solution was also mentioned in the comments, I think. Oh, it was *your* comment...) (I didn't downvote, it was just an informative comment.)

Comment: @WolframH: Yes, I was thinking it better fits as an answer. Anyway, the answer does give a solution for the *original* question, by using a reduction to a well known domain, which is usually prefered.

Comment: Please mention the original question in your answer and I'll upvote. As it is, there is a chance of confusion for "newcomers".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to minimize the number of external operations `get` and `reverse`:

- read all integers into an internal array by calling `get` n times
- do an internal sort (n log in internal ops) and calculate the permutation
- sort the external array by calling `reverse` a maximum of n times

This has O(n) time and O(n) space complexity.

**Edit** in response to anonymous downvotes:
when talking about time complexity, you always have to state, which operations are to be counted. Here I assumed, only the external operations have a cost.

Comment: Seems like going around the rules. Why do you think that counting `get` and `reverse` is enough for calculating time complexity? How do you know you have any internal memory? Assuming is not enough, I assume the opposite. Someone can even assume that there is a not mentioned O(1) sort of the external array.

Comment: @JurajBlaho - which rules? The rules were not completely stated, so I filled in the gaps. My assumption may or may not be correct. But based on this assumption, I think my answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the rules are not clear. But if you can arbitrarily fill the gap you can do that in O(1). The rules didn't state that there is no internal memory and also they didn't state that there is no O(1) sort operation. So I think that the answer is not correct and that's why I downvoted.

Comment: @JurajBlaho - no, you can never do it in O(1). How would you sort the external array in O(1), given the fact that it's explicitely stated that get and reverse have cost O(1)?

Comment: Please, reread my comments. Just by thinking up an O(1) external sort.

Comment: @JurajBlaho - I did not make up an O(1) external sort. Consider access to the external array is expensive, e.g. because it is on a remote computer. Then it makes sense, to read in all data, do an internal sort (O(nlogn) internal operations, but those are cheap), and then issue O(n) reverse commands to the remote computer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13031/discussion-between-juraj-blaho-and-henrik)

Answer (score 0):

Based on get(int i) and reverse( int i, int j), we can't optimise the code. It will have same complexity.